# custom imageview in larger layout

Tags: android

Having a bit of trouble here. I've created a custom ImageView by subclassing ImageView and I'm able to get it to display if I simply instantiate my view and set the entire contentView of my activity to my imageview via `setContentView(myCustomImageView)`

But what if I want to just use my custom imageview as part of a larger layout? E.g., I want a button, a textview, etc and then my ImageView somewhere in there...

I tried doing something like programatically creating a linearlayout and then instantiating my special imageview and adding it via `mLinearLayout.addView(myCustomImageView)` but it crashes when I do this.

Am I missing something basic here?

EDIT: apparently you just use the full namespace of your custom view in the XML.

Comment: yeah, you can use xml. not only to create the layout entirely but also to include custom views written prorammatically. An xml relative layout that will display your java written widgets where you want them would fit very nicely.

Comment: What does the logcat say when it crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you put your layout in the XML?

You can add you custom `View` like this:

```
<view
    class="com.your_package.myCustomImageView" 
    id="@+id/customView"
/>
```

You can find more useful resources on [the Android SDK documentation site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

**Edit**: Yes, you must use the entire namespace for your self defined views. For standard views you can omit `com.android.widget` because the SDK knows where to find them, but for your own stuff he doesn't.

Comment: An example:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278634/forced-close-after-adding-custom-imageview